# Amazon S3 bucket policy deny to a iam user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, policy

To all AWS experts:

Error : Policy has invalid action

Trying to Deny access to a IAM user via bucket policy. AWS document shows as an example but its not working. Am I doing something wrong?

Bucket Policy JSON:

```
{
 "Id": "Policy1630065308389",
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt1630065306314",
   "Action": [
    "s3:DeleteBucket",
    "s3:GetObject"
   ],
   "Effect": "Deny",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketv11/*",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::673863497215:user/mom-tester"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `s3:DeleteBucket` action is a bucket-level action so you cannot apply it to the resource `"arn:aws:s3:::mybucketv11/*"`, which is an object-level resource.

Your bucket policy would look more like this:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1630065308389",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "s1",
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketv11/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::673863497215:user/mom-tester"
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "s2",
      "Action": ["s3:DeleteBucket"],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketv11",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::673863497215:user/mom-tester"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That said, why are you using an S3 bucket policy to deny access to the IAM user? Why not simply modify the permissions/roles of the IAM user so as not to allow access to this bucket?

Comment: Excellent, I am practicing aws and what to try all permutations and combinations and then stick to standard practices. Thanks, it worked.

Comment: OK good, but remember that typically you would solve this from an identity policy perspective rather than resource policy. See [the differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html).

Comment: Sure.. thanks a ton. Also learned that, ACL overrides bucket policy and in turn it overrides iam policy..

Comment: Note that ACLs are a legacy control mechanism. You should typically not use them, if you can avoid it.

Comment: The basic rule is that a `Deny` always overrides an `Allow`, regardless of where they came from.